# Using CheckPoint SNX with RSA SecurID Software Token to connect to VPN

Tags: 10.10, vpn

I have a fairly specific issue that I'm hoping someone else out in the community has had to tackle with success.

My company uses CheckPoint VPN clients on Windows XP machines with RSA SecurID software to generate the tokens.  The beauty is that once you generate a token code on the software, you can enter it into any machine trying to connect via VPN and with your username get connected.

So, I've got Ubuntu 10.10 32bit on a tower and formerly on a laptop.  Through several posts around the web, I was able to get SNX installed on the laptop, plug in my server connection information and be asked for a password only to have the connection fail.

I used to debug mode and was able to see that the application was trying to and failing at writing a registry value, but I believe that to be a symptom of a different issue, even though I tried to find a way to remedy that.

I'm wondering if anyone out there is on a similar configuration and was able to connect with SNX using an RSA token?  If so, what steps did you take to setup and what problems/solutions did you encounter?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. Unfortunately snx on Linux does not support interactive SecureID authentication. So you and I are SOL.

Comment: This question appears to be abandonded, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag explaining that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no support for SNX with the RSA token.

Answer (score 2):

I'm successfully connected to VPN using Check Point SNX build 800005013 with RSA SecurID Token as password.

Following this tutorial http://kevin.deldycke.com/2012/04/check-point-snx-client-ubuntu/

Since RSA SecurID not available on linux. You can use wine to installed windows version of RSA SecurID. Or, you can use iOS/Android version of RSA SecurID.

I'm using xubuntu 12.04

Comment: Hi, Was this with two-factor authentication (PIN+SecurID token) or only with the SecurID token?

Comment: SecurID token only. SecurID token it self has PIN on it.